# React JS Object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In below code i have not declared showPerson property in person object. But am getting result. Button has hide and show content when you click on button. Its working fine for me. But still i have doubt how come without declaring the property in object. Please explain it in simplest way.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import Person from "./Person/Person";

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    person: [
      { name: "Andrew", age: 32 },
      { name: "Stephen", age: 42 },
      { name: "Samuel", age: 62 }
    ]
  };

  changeTxt = () => {
    const doesShow = this.state.showPerson;
    this.setState({ showPerson: !doesShow });
  };

  render() {
    let person = null;

    if (this.state.showPerson) {
      person = (
        <div>
          <Person
            name={this.state.person[0].name}
            age={this.state.person[0].age}
          />
          <Person
            name={this.state.person[1].name}
            age={this.state.person[1].age}
            changed={this.changeMethod}
          />
          <Person
            name={this.state.person[2].name}
            age={this.state.person[2].age}
          />
        </div>
      );
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.changeTxt}>Click here</button>
        {person}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: *"Please explain it in simplest way."* Accessing a property that doesn't exist returns `undefined`. `undefined` converts to `false`. See: `var obj = {}; console.log(obj.foo, Boolean(obj.foo));`. That has nothing to do with React, it's how JavaScript works.

Comment: `this.state.showPerson` is `undefined` at first, and `!undefined` is `true`.

Comment: *"Write a title that summarizes the specific problem*". Please read: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask):

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you `console.log(showPerson)` without setting it. You will see that, its `undefined`. But after setting it you will see that it has the value. You don't have to initialize them.

Now the reason this code still works is that in javascript there are `falsy` and `truthy` values. These values react as `true` or `false` values in if statements.

undefined is a falsy value so it pretends like false in if statements. And when you change the value to this: `!undefined`. Since `!falsy === true` `showPerson` becomes true

Comment: Thanks for explaining in a simple way.

Comment: @Faruk No problem good luck with your project :) Don't forget to upvote the question :)

Answer (score 0):

Your question not clear but from my understanding, your code works and you want to make your code much simple

If so separate you if-else to different function and render it

```
    import React, { Component } from "react";
    import "./App.css";
    import Person from "./Person/Person";

        class App extends Component {
          state = {
            person: [
              { name: "Andrew", age: 32 },
              { name: "Stephen", age: 42 },
              { name: "Samuel", age: 62 }
            ]
          };

          changeTxt = () => {
            const doesShow = this.state.showPerson;
            this.setState({ showPerson: !doesShow });
          };


          renderPerson = () => {
              if (this.state.showPerson) {
              return (
                <div>
                  <Person
                    name={this.state.person[0].name}
                    age={this.state.person[0].age}
                  />
                  <Person
                    name={this.state.person[1].name}
                    age={this.state.person[1].age}
                    changed={this.changeMethod}
                  />
                  <Person
                    name={this.state.person[2].name}
                    age={this.state.person[2].age}
                  />
                </div>
              )
            }else{
                return null // your fallback
            }

          }

          render() {
            return (
              <div>
                <button onClick={this.changeTxt}>Click here</button>
                {this.renderPerson()}
              </div>
            );
          }
        }

        export default App;
```